# I have a issue with CanCollide on roblox and I was wondering if it was something in my code?

Tags: lua, roblox

Ok so my issue is that I wrote this piece of code that will add a trail or "streak" behind you when you run. And im trying to make it so he has clothes as well. But when the humanoid is added it CanCollides everything. Not sure why. I was wondering if something in my code suggested that everything be CanCollided.
Here is the code.

http://pastebin.com/npi7XfRc

Answer (score 0):

From what I was able to see in your code, it appears as though you're setting the Right Arm's CanCollide to true. that may be the problem. If that's not it, then it may be the FormDegen clones you're making. Try setting those to CanCollide false, and see if that fixes your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The humanoid automatically sets certain parts' CanCollide to true and others, to false. Usually, the arms and legs are false and the rest of the body is true.